# What is this structure in javascript return({object}={})=>{more code}?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to understand what this code is doing, it's from a nodejs.
I don't understand what is this structure is doing

return({object}={})=>{more code}

you can find the repository here:
https://github.com/howardmann/clean-node/blob/master/models/teacher/teacher.js

```js
let buildMakeTeacher = function(teacherValidator) {
  return ({
    name,
    subject,
    tenure = false
  } = {}) => {
    let {error} = teacherValidator({name, subject, tenure})
    if (error) throw new Error(error)

    return {
      getName: () => name,
      getSubject: () => subject,
      isTenure: () => tenure
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's returning a function. `({object})` is a destructuring parameter.

Comment: What exactly are you confused about, what parts do you understand? Do you know what `return (…) => {…};` is intended to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to answer by @Sarkar, the amount of curly braces here may shock you. The point of others (that don't declare a scope) is [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Breaking down:

```js
let {error} = teacherValidator({name, subject, tenure})
```

This line takes object returned by `teacherValidator` and extracts a key named `error` from it. If it returned, say, `{error: 'Fail', errorcode: 1}`, then `error` is assigned to `'Fail'`.

```js
return ({
  name,
  subject,
  tenure = false
} = {}) => { doSomething(); }
```

This creates an anonymous function with complex argument handling. It is (by calling result, implementation should differ) equivalent to:

```
return function(params={}) {
  let {name, subject, tenure=false} = params;
  doSomething();
}
```

This function:

- When called without args, has params set to empty object;
- When called with argument, extracts `name` and `subject` keys from it (`undefined` if not present) and `tenure` key (`false` if missing).
- Performs some action with these args (checks error and returns object with 3 anonymous functions like getters)

Comment: I'd also mention, that the act of returning a function, in a function, is known as `curry`ing (named after Haskell Curry) [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying ]. As such, when you wanted to run this, you would have to call it with double parentheses, like: `const tmp = buildMakeTeacher(someValidator)({name: 'Bill Nigh', subject: 'Science', ignored: true});`. In this example, `tmp.getName(); // 'Bill Nigh'`, `tmp.getSubject(); // Science`, and, `tmp.isTenure(); // false`. The `ignored: true` is effectively ignored, as no part of the curried function uses it, and it's lost in the closure.

Answer (score -1):

It's a anonymous function

this

```
(object)=>{more code}
```

is equivalent to this

```
function functionName(object){
   moreCode
}
```

your code example is  a function called `buildMakeTeacher` which is returning an anonymous function which returns an object

Answer (score -1):

Read about closure and curry a bit it will give you a better perspective.

But basically that means this function returns a new function which returns an object with callable actions.

So to call it you should do something like
buildMakeTeacher(someValidstor)({name: “foo”, subject: “bar”}).getSubject()